# Qt Creator or qmake on MacOSX build library as ".so" not dylib

Tags: c++, macos, qt, qt-creator, qmake

I need to build my plugin/library as a .so on Mac. That happens without extra trick on Linux and works like a charm.

What extra options I need to add to my .pro file?

```
CONFIG += debug
QT += xml
TEMPLATE = lib
TARGET = mylib
DEPENDPATH += .
macx:INCLUDEPATH += ../../../Test \
  /usr/local/include/

macx:LIBS += -L../../../Test/lib

DEFINES += CORE_EXPORT=
DEFINES += GUI_EXPORT=

HEADERS += test.h testGui.h
FORMS += testGui.ui
SOURCES += test.cpp testGui.cpp
RESOURCES += test.qrc
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ".so" suffix doesn't mean anything on OS X. On an ELF platform like Linux, an "*.so" file is a shared library. On OS X, shared libraries have the ".dylib" extension. On Linux, plugins are implemented as shared libraries (*.so) because you can unload them again when you're done with them. On OS X, shared libraries cannot be unloaded. That makes them unsuitable for plugins.

On OS X, you use bundles instead of shared libraries in order to implement plugins. Last time I looked, qmake doesn't support this directly. But you can modify the linker flags in order to build a bundle.  By default, qmake uses the "-dynamiclib" linker flag, which builds a *.dylib. Instead, you should use the "-bundle" flag, which builds bundles. You can try this:

```
CONFIG += plugin
QMAKE_LFLAGS_PLUGIN -= -dynamiclib
QMAKE_LFLAGS_PLUGIN += -bundle
```

The file extension of a bundle is not standardized. You can use whatever you want (.so, .dylib, .plugin, .donald_duck, ...) Apple recommends ".bundle", but doesn't enforce it. To control the filename of the created bundle, you can set `QMAKE_EXTENSION_SHLIB` and `QMAKE_PREFIX_SHLIB`. For example, to get `mylib.bundle`, set:

```
QMAKE_EXTENSION_SHLIB = bundle
QMAKE_PREFIX_SHLIB =
```

If instead you want to get `libmylib.so`, only set:

```
QMAKE_PREFIX_SHLIB = so
```

As the names suggest, `QMAKE_EXTENSION_SHLIB` contains the file extension (without the `.`), and `QMAKE_PREFIX_SHLIB` contains the file prefix (by default it's `lib`).

Comment: Thanks Niko Ill try it. Tasos

Comment: Its not really working. I added the flags so I get a bundle.

g++-4.2 -headerpad_max_install_names -F../lib -arch x86_64 -single_module -bundle -Xarch_x86_64 -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -o libdoo.dylib debug/doo.o debug/......

But I get a dylib again (its not rename to .so thing, not working).

Comment: Does it help if you add these two lines: `QMAKE_EXTENSION_SHLIB = bundle` and `QMAKE_PREFIX_SHLIB =` This should produce a `doo.bundle` instead of a `libdoo.dylib`. If you really want a `libdoo.so`, then only add this line: `QMAKE_EXTENSION_SHLIB = so`.

Answer (score 0):

you may need to put the -dynamiclibs line after bundle... works for me.

found here:

http://jonmacey.blogspot.com/2012/03/using-maya-api-with-qt-creator.html