# Qt creates dylib instead of bundle on MacOS ignoring the flags

Tags: macos, qt, bundle

I have stuck with Qt and it's flags to force bundle compilation instead of dylib on Mac. I have found and read next posts: http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/1119, [Qt Creator or qmake on MacOSX build library as ".so" not dylib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12977739/qt-creator-or-qmake-on-macosx-build-library-as-so-not-dylib), however, I still can't make things working.

I have following .pro:

```
macx {
    TEMPLATE = lib
    CONFIG += plugin
    QMAKE_LFLAGS_PLUGIN -= -dynamiclib
    QMAKE_LFLAGS_PLUGIN += -bundle
    QMAKE_EXTENSION_SHLIB = bundle

    # Sources, headers etc.
}
```

And it doesn't work at all. Whatever options I push - it's still dylib. `CONFIG += lib_bundle` produces framework, which doesn't work for me again...

I guess I'm missing something simple, but so far I have spent few hours trying to figure out where the problem lays with no success.

I'd appreciate any help with this.

Comment: same problem. did you solved your problem? mind sharing how?

Answer (score 0):

Later Qt versions might not need quite so much tweaking, but this works with Qt 4.8.1:

```
TEMPLATE = lib

macx {
    CONFIG += lib_bundle
    QMAKE_LFLAGS += -bundle
    QMAKE_LFLAGS_SHLIB -= -dynamiclib
    QMAKE_LFLAGS_VERSION = ""
    QMAKE_LFLAGS_COMPAT_VERSION = ""
    QMAKE_LFLAGS_SONAME = ""
}
```